# jQuery Form validation color change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

2 questions. i am learning form validation in javascript/jQuery

1) as you can see when there is not input , background color is pink, but when i start typing the background color is not going away. i tried with else if 'remove class' still no good. i want to achieve this using jQuery only

2)(html)when i click sign-up , I want document page to go to a different html page. how do i achieve this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 if($("#fnameid,#Lnameid,#emailid,#phoneid,#dob-day,#dob-month,#dob-year,#mf").val(null)){
  $("#fnameid,#Lnameid,#emailid,#phoneid,#dob-day,#dob-month,#dob-year,#mf").addClass("bordercoloron");
 }
});
```

```css
#wraper {
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 4000px;
 width: 1000px;
 border: 2px solid black;
}
#wholeform {
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 600px;
 width: 400px;
 border: 2px solid grey;
}
#fnameid, #Lnameid {
 height: 50px;
 width: 172px;
 border: none;
 position: relative;
 left: 0.5%;
 margin-top: 3%;
 padding-left: 5%;
 font-size: 20px;
}
#emailid, #phoneid {
 height: 50px;
 width: 372px;
 border: none;
 position: relative;
 left: 0.5%;
 font-size: 20px;
 padding-left: 5%;
 letter-spacing: 9px;
 margin-top: 5%;
}
#dob-day, #dob-month, #dob-year {
 height: 50px;
 width: 120px;
 position: relative;
 left: 4%;
 border: none;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-top: 5%;
 color: darkgray
}
#mf {
 height: 55px;
 width: 350px;
 position: relative;
 left: 4%;
 border: none;
 font-size: 50px;
 margin-top: -2%;
 padding-left: 5%;
 letter-spacing: 10px;
 color: darkgray
}
.bordercoloron {
 background-color: coral;
}
.bordercoloroff {
 border: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jexercise.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="mainbox">
    <form  id="wholeform">
      <input type="text" placeholder="FirstName" name="fname" id="fnameid">
      <input type="text" placeholder="LastName" name="Lname" id="Lnameid">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email@example.com" name="email" id="emailid">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile Phone Number" name="fname" id="phoneid">
      <select name="dob-day" id="dob-day">
        <option value="">Day</option>
        <option value="">---</option>
        <option value="01">01</option>
        <option value="02">02</option>
        <option value="03">03</option>
        <option value="04">04</option>
        <option value="05">05</option>
        <option value="06">06</option>
        <option value="07">07</option>
        <option value="08">08</option>
        <option value="09">09</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
      </select>
      <select name="dob-month" id="dob-month">
        <option value="">Month</option>
        <option value="">-----</option>
        <option value="01">January</option>
        <option value="02">February</option>
        <option value="03">March</option>
        <option value="04">April</option>
        <option value="05">May</option>
        <option value="06">June</option>
        <option value="07">July</option>
        <option value="08">August</option>
        <option value="09">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
      </select>
      <select name="dob-year" id="dob-year">
        <option value="">Year</option>
        <option value="">----</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
        <option value="2008">2008</option>
        <option value="2007">2007</option>
        <option value="2006">2006</option>
        <option value="2005">2005</option>
        <option value="2004">2004</option>
        <option value="2003">2003</option>
        <option value="2002">2002</option>
        <option value="2001">2001</option>
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
        <option value="1999">1999</option>
        <option value="1998">1998</option>
        <option value="1997">1997</option>
        <option value="1996">1996</option>
        <option value="1995">1995</option>
        <option value="1994">1994</option>
        <option value="1993">1993</option>
        <option value="1992">1992</option>
        <option value="1991">1991</option>
      </select>
      <h3 style="font-size:20px; position: relative; left:5%; width:70px;color:darkgray;">Gender:</h3>
      <select id="mf">
        <option>Male</option>
        <option>Female</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" id="submit" style="background-color:#2196F3;border-radius:5px;border:2px #2196F3;position:relative; margin-top:25%;left:25%;width:200px;height:80px;font-size:50px;color:darkgray; padding-left:5%;" value="SignUp">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="../js/jexercise.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does it mean `$('#fnameid,...').val(null)`?

Comment: all those are input tags. so if there no texts(null) the color should on if there is text no color

Comment: Link how to use val() method: http://api.jquery.com/val/ You can read it before continuing to doing next step

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1 : If removeClass is not working properly, use removeAttr i.e.,

```
$("#fnameid,#Lnameid,#emailid,#phoneid,#dob-day,#dob-month,#dob-year,#mf").removeAttr("class");
```

Answer 2 : Add function on button click as below :

```
<input type="button" id="submit" onClick="myFunc()"  value="SignUp">
```

Now declare function in your javascript i.e., :

```
var myFunc = function(){
 window.location.href = 'Redirection Link';
}
```

Comment: page redirect works like a charm thank-you. but change removeattribute still not

Comment: I don't know why, but this code of removeAttr() is working properly at my side. Check it once.